# why code always print True.whenever i check for equal but not print the given string always print boolean

Tags: class

'why code always print True.whenever i check for equal but not print the given string always print boolean'

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __sub__(self,other):
        first = self.x-other.x
        second = self.y-other.y
        return (first,second)
    def __mul__(self,other):
        first = self.x*other.x
        second = self.y*other.y
        return (first,second)
    def __eq__(self,other):
        if self in other:
            
            return 'The calculated coordinates are the same.'
        else:    
            return 'The calculated coordinates are NOT the same.'
        
    
p1 = Coordinates(int(input()),int(input()))
p2 = Coordinates(int(input()),int(input()))
p4 = p1 - p2
print(p4)
p5 = p1 * p2
print(p5)
p6 = (p4 == p5)
print(p6)
```

'last line==>> print(p6)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of `p4` and `p5` is *tuple*. They are not instances of the `Coordinates` class, so when you compare them you get a `True` or `False`. If your `__sub__()` and `__mul__()` methods returned an instance of `Coordinates` class instead of just a tuple, the equality comparison would return one of the strings you've written there.

EDIT: Replace your class with this and it will work:

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __sub__(self,other):
        first = self.x - other.x
        second = self.y - other.y
        return Coordinates(first, second)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        first = self.x * other.x
        second = self.y * other.y
        return Coordinates(first, second)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y:
            return 'The calculated coordinates are the same.'
        else:    
            return 'The calculated coordinates are NOT the same.'
```

Comment: Sample Input 1:
1
2
3
4
Sample Output 1:
(-2,-2)
(3,8)
The calculated coordinates are NOT the same......i want this type of output...;)

Comment: Okay I implemented the solution for you :)